# How can I change outer part of hair to remove pinkish hue - photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, creative-cloud

I am editing a photograph which I've masked out the woman from the background but she has a pinkish hue on the edge of her hair. I am not sure what the best way to go about selecting the hair as I only want the pinkish parts. I am assuming I would need to create some kind of mask of just that section of hair but on another layer?

Also once it has been masked I don't know how to change the colour. I have tried hue and saturation but I want the colour to be similar to the brown hair, as close as I can get.

Alternatively if there was a brush I could brush over the pink bits to change the colour like a transparency mode.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you aren't using the Select and Mask functionality in Photoshop for background removal.

Make a selection of the model, and refine your mask using the Select and Mask button.  For a full tutorial on using Select and Mask, check [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+select+and+mask).

In the Select and Mask workspace there is a feature called Decontaminate Colors. Enable it, and move the slider to remove the contaminated pixels.  These are only present because of the colour of the background you are removing (pink in this case)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use any brush loaded with a brown (or desired color), then set the brush **blend mode** to `Color` or `Hue` and brush over the areas. It may be easier to load a selection of the head first, that way you can *only* paint inside the selection.

You could also use the **Sponge Tool** set to `Desaturate` to merely remove color.