# Cannot remove colors in PS selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, selections

I'm using Photoshop on an image of a horse, trying to paste the image into another background.  The selection has leftover green from grass in the original background, especially around the horse's tail.  I'm trying to use Select->Color Range, but it either errors, "No Pixels Selected" or I'm unable to do anything with the selected green.  Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159220/how-can-i-change-outer-part-of-hair-to-remove-pinkish-hue-photoshop-cc